# Number of automorphisms of a group with $n$ generators.

Tags: group-theory

Is the number of automorphisms of a group with $n$ generators simply $n!$?

Motivation: If we bijectively map the set of generators of a group to itself, which can be done in $n!$ ways, we get a unique automorphism for each such bijection. And to construct an automorphism, we have to map generators to generators. If we don't map a generator to a generator, the mapping won't be surjective.

EDIT: Now my basic question is if there are $a$ distinct sets of generators, should the upper limit of the number of automorphisms be ${a\choose 2} n!$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. All symmetric groups are $2$-generated, but they are isomorphic to their automorphism groups (with a few exceptions). Very few groups will have automorphism group of order $n!$ for any $n$, let alone the number of generators.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: So $n!$ can be like a upper bound here?

Comment: Not remotely. As Tobias said, symmetric groups are usually isomorphic to their automorphism group, meaning there are as many automorphisms as elements of the group, in that case. Likewise for linear automorphisms on a multi-dimensional vector space over your favorite number field.

Comment: Actually, I now reread the question, and maybe number of generators is not meant as minimal number of generators but rather as the number of elements that (each) generate the group (which is possibly assumed cyclic). In which case, $n!$ is too large by a large margin except for very small groups.

Comment: @CameronBuie: I see. Thank you both. Yes that is a remote milestone here.

Answer (score 4):

I think if we consider $S_4$ which has the presentation as follows $$\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^4=(ab)^3=1\rangle$$ then as $S_4$ is a complete group, i.e.; $S_4=Aut(S_4)$ so we face to a contradiction.

Comment: Deserves another TU!

Comment: Say every set of generators of the group has $n$ elements, and that there are $a$ such distinct sets. For surjectivity of the homomorphism, we have to map generators to generators. Can we say $a.n!$ is the upper bound of the number of automorphisms?

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that generators can usually be chosen in different ways, just like bases for vector spaces. A linear automorphism needn't map basis elements to elements of the same basis, so why should a more general automorphism?

Comment: Say every set of generators of the group has $n$ elements, and that there are $a$ such distinct sets. For surjectivity of the homomorphism, we have to map generators to generators. Can we say $a.n!$ is the upper bound of the number of automorphisms?

Comment: That sounds right, but I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Sorry I think it shold be ${a\choose 2} n!$, as any two of the $a$ sets of generators can be chosen.

Comment: I don't think so, actually. It seems to me that, given any set of generators, an automorphism is determined by which set of generators the original set is mapped to (the $a$ part) and how (the $n!$ part). It's possible that I'm missing something, though.